# Outlook auto replacing links with anchor

Tags: outlook, html-email

In my email template I have an import to use a web font:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300");
```

Outlook is replacing the url content with a anchor:

```
@import url("<a href="http: //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" class="">http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300</a>");
```

I tried  instead but same result, what is missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook doesn't really understand `@import` or `@font-face`, so whenever you use those in email you need to add an MSO conditional around the style tag.

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<style type="text/css">
     @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300");
</style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: I didn't found my solution in documentation you mention, could you point me a direction?

Comment: I've seen this guy post this exact answer at least 20 times. The MSDN docs are helpful for understanding Microsoft's VML language for Outlook but don't help at all for Outlook's HTML rendering quirks.